# How to get rid of pygame surfaces?

Tags: python, pygame, geometry-surface

In the following code, there is not just **one** circle on the screen at any given point in time.
I want to fix this to make it so that it looks like there is only one circle, instead of leaving a smudge trail where ever the mouse cursor has been.

```
import pygame,sys
from pygame.locals import *
pygame.init()

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((640,400),0,32)

radius = 25
circle = pygame.Surface([radius*2]*2,SRCALPHA,32)
circle = circle.convert_alpha()
pygame.draw.circle(circle,(25,46,100),[radius]*2,radius)

while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()

    screen.blit(circle,(pygame.mouse.get_pos()[0],100))

    pygame.display.update()
    pygame.time.delay(10)
```

Answer (score 6):

You need to specifically erase the circle before you blit it again. Depending on how complicated your scene is, you may have to try different methods. Generally what I do is have a "background" surface that a blit to the screen every frame and then blit the sprites/other surfaces in their new positions (blits in Pygame are very fast, so even in fairly large screens I haven't had speed issues doing this). For your code above, it's simple enough just to use `surface.fill(COLOR)` where `COLOR` is your background color; eg, (255,255,255) for white:

```
# ...
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((640,400),0,32)
backgroundColor = (255,255,255)
# ...
while True:
    # ...
    screen.fill(backgroundColor)
    screen.blit(circle,(pygame.mouse.get_pos()[0],100))
    pygame.display.update()
    pygame.time.delay(10)
```

**Edit** in answer to your comment: It is possible to do this in a more object-oriented way.

You will need to have a background Surface associated with your screen (I usually have a Display or Map class (depending on the type of game) that does this). Then, make your object a subclass of `pygame.sprite`. This requires that you have `self.image` and `self.rect` attributes (the image being your surface and the rect being a Pygame.rect with the location). Add all of your sprites to a `pygame.group` object. Now, every frame, you call the `draw` method on the group and, after you update the display (ie, with pygame.display.update()), you call the `clear` method on the group. This method requires that you provide both the destination surface (ie, `screen` above) and a background image.

For example, your main loop may look more like this:

```
while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()

    circle.rect.center = (pygame.mouse.get_pos()[0],100)
    circleGroup.draw(screen)

    pygame.display.update()
    circleGroup.clear(screen, backgroundSurface)
    pygame.time.delay(10)
```

See the [documentation](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html) on the Sprite and Group classes for more information.

Comment: This method works and is effective, but is there a more object oriented approach? I am planning to make this a class object, so I was wondering if there was another way that doesn't use screen.fill(bgColor).