# Why wont my score update

Tags: python, pygame

```
 keepGoing = True
 while keepGoing:
     score+=1
     myfont = pygame.font.SysFont("monospace", 15)
     label = myfont.render(str(score), 1, (255,255,0))
     screen.blit(label, (100, 100))
```

This is my code but when I run the program it increases score properly - but when outputting it to the screen it doesn't take previous digit off, so when it prints 1 on the screen and then a 2 the 1 doesn't erase the 2 shows write on top of it. Because of this after a while I just get a yellow block on the screen.

Comment: I dont know why my code wont show up

Comment: I agree with reopen, user added description of the exact problem.

Comment: what are you saying JasonMArcher

Comment: The question was closed because people thought you were unclear.  Your edit automatically started a reopen vote and we felt that you had added enough detail.  :)

Comment: So now that it is open when will I get an answer to my question?

Comment: I will take a stab at answering, but I don't know Python.

Answer (score 1):

You're getting the error

```
NameError: name 'score' is not defined
```

because you're trying to update a variable that hasn't yet been defined. Even though the `+=` contains an equal sign, you still need to define `score` before using `+=`

```
keepGoing = True
score = 0

while keepGoing:
    score += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

you should define score out while, like

```
keepGoing = True
score = 0
```

then it works.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know python, but based on the symptoms my guess would be that you have to clear the screen before you write something new.  This question might be the way to do that.

[How to get rid of pygame surfaces?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2215227/how-to-get-rid-of-pygame-surfaces)