# How to remove surface from window while the game is running

Tags: pygame, command, window, display

I'm making this space invaders type game with pygame and I have this issue where, enemies keep spawning while the time is stopped. I need a fix that removes those enemies from the window ( I use .blit to display my surfaces) right after the time is started again.

E.G:

```
def draw_on_window(enemy):
   window.blit(enemy)

def main():

    # Command that clears the window of "Enemy surfaces" somehow?? :   
    # window.remove(enemy) ?? 

   run = True
   while run:
     draw_on_window(blue_enemy)
     #game
```

Comment: Your code does not provide an option of stopping the game ( or stopping `time` ). Provide a minimal actually working code showing the problem you are facing.

Comment: See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2215227/how-to-get-rid-of-pygame-surfaces#2215258 and consider to `draw_on_window(enemy_with_background_color).

Comment: Just remove the enemy from the list.

Answer (score 0):

In pygame you don't remove something from a surface like the window. `window.blit(image)` draws an image to the window surface.

To clear everything you have to fill the window black.

In pygame you do the following things your main loop normally:

- fill the screen black `window.fill((0, 0, 0))`
- draw everything again
- handle all [events](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html) (eg. QUIT, MOUSEBUTTONDOWN...)
- let the [clock](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/time.html#pygame.time.Clock) tick at a specified frame rate

```
enemy_coords = [(5, 9), (3, 4)] # just an example
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
max_fps = 60

while run:
    window.fill((0, 0, 0)) # fill the window with black

    for coord in enemy_coords:
        window.blit(enemy_image, coord)

    do_events...

    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(max_fps)
```

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is manage the enemies in a list and remove the enemies from the list (see [How to remove items from a list while iterating?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207406/how-to-remove-items-from-a-list-while-iterating)). Draw only the enemies that are in the list.
e.g.: represent the enemies by [`pygame.Rect`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html) objects and remove them when they are out of the window:

```py
def draw_on_window(enemies):
   for enemy_rect in enemies:
       window.blit(enemy_image, enemy_rect)
```

```py
def main():
    enemies = []
    enemies.append(pygame.Rect(x1, y1, w, h))
    enemies.append(pygame.Rect(x2, y2, w, h))
    
    run = True
    while run:
        
        # [...]

        for enemy in enemies[:]:
            if not enemies.colliderect(window.get_rect())
                enemies.remove(enemy)

        # [...]
       
        draw_on_window(enemies)
        pygame.dispaly.update()
```

You can remove all items from a list with the [`clear()`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html) method:

```py
enemies.clear()
```